# Check if word contains substrings

Tags: python, pandas

### Question

Consider the following:

```
word = 'analphabetic'
df = pd.DataFrame({'substring': list('abcdefgh') + ['ab', 'phobic']})
```

#### substring is not necessarily a single letter!

I want to add a column with the name of `word` and each row it shows `True/False` whether the substring in that row is in `word`. Can I do this with a built-in pandas method?

Desired output:

```
  substring  analphabetic
0         a          True
1         b          True
2         c          True
3         d         False
4         e          True
5         f         False
6         g         False
7         h          True
8         ab         True
9         phobic    False
```

### pandas.Series.str.contains

The other way around can be done by doing something like `df.substring.str.contains(word)`. I guess you could do something like:

```
df[word] = [i in word for i in df.substring]
```

But then the built-in function `str.contains()` could be done by:

```
string = 'a'
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': ['these', 'are', 'some', 'random', 'words']})
df[string] = [string in i for i in df.words]
```

So my thought is that there is also a built-in method to do my trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (which should work for substrings longer than a single letter):

```
df['analphabetic'] = df['substring'].map(lambda x: x in word)
```

Output:

```
  substring  analphabetic
0         a          True
1         b          True
2         c          True
3         d         False
4         e          True
5         f         False
6         g         False
7         h          True
```

---

Using list comprehension:

```
df['analphabetic'] = [x in word for x in df.substring]
```

---

Using `apply`:

```
df['analphabetic'] = df['substring'].apply(lambda x: x in word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use the `contains` to Find a Substring in a Pandas DataFrame.

You can also use the     `in` Operator, the `in` operator is used to check data structures in Python.  It  also returns a Boolean (either True or False)